# Stop saving to JSON File when mouse is out of the broswer

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, event-handling, mouseevent

I am currently saving mouse movement co-ordinates to a JSON file every 1 second through the use of the following:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(track, 1000);
}
```

track is the function that is saving the coordinates to the json file through ajax.

However by using this method when the mouse is not on the browser, the function is still refreshing every second and is therefore taking the last saved co-ordinates in event.clientX/Y.

I am aware of the onmouseenter and onmouseout functions, however i have not been successful in implementing them for my purpose. I have tested the functions out as follows:

```
document.onmouseenter = function(i){
  console.log('IN');
}

document.onmouseleave = function(l){
  console.log('OUT');
}
```

However, the above onmouseenter funtion only outputs 'IN' when the first click is made. While the onmouseleave function never outputs 'OUT'.

Any Suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could simply compare the new mouse position with the last tracked position and decide not to log it if it has not changed.

Comment: however i would like to track all mouse activity on the website, so unfortunately that cannot be done :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about unsetting x/y after saving then checking if they're set when you try to save?

```
var x, y; // store mouse coords

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (x !== undefined && y !== undefined) { // check if they're set
    // save your locations, only called when mouse is moved on page
    x = y = undefined; // unset them
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user the below code. Modify it as per your requirement if necessary.
Basically you need to **handle the following Events :**

1. Window Load
2. Tab Focus
3. Window Blur [Instead of Mouse Out]
4. Window Before Unload [Before closing the Browser]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).load(function() {
    // Call your function to START storing the data
  });

  $(window).focus(function() {
    // Call your function to START storing the data
  });

  $(window).blur(function() {
    // Call your function to STOP storing the data
  });

  //tabCloseEvent();
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    // Call your function to STOP storing the data
  });



});
```